# WinAPI create window + child windows, process a button press?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, button, createwindow

I'm new to **WinApi** and I'm looking to create a simple window inside my program containing a blank **parent window and two smaller child buttons** "button1" & "button2". with this button I'm hoping to change a bool value from false to true and visa versa, but nearly all the examples I have seen are quite hard to understand, it seems like you have to return an **MSG** value of some kind which I don't know how to process.

I have a **pseudocode** below of what I'm trying to do, I have left comments explaining what I want to do at each moment, am I going about it the right way?:

```
#include <windows.h>

static int buildwindow(){

    MSG msg;

    //create parent window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("scrollbar"), TEXT("Parent"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP,
    10, 10, 800, 500, NULL, NULL, NULL,  NULL);

    //create child window
    HWND hWnd1 = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("button1"), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP,
    10, 10, 80, 25, hWnd, NULL, NULL,  NULL);

    //create child window2
    HWND hWnd2 = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("button2"), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP,
    100, 100, 80, 25, hWnd, NULL, NULL,  NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    ShowWindow(hWnd1, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd1);
    ShowWindow(hWnd2, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd2);

    //wait for buttonpress
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    //return the buttonpress
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



int main(void)
{

   //create window inside the buttonpress method
   int buttonpress = buildwindow();

   //check which button was pressed
   if(buttonpress = button1){
      //do something
   }
   elseif(buttonpress = button2){
      //do something else
   }
   //finish
   return(0);

}
```

Comment: There are countless examples on basic WinAPI programming out there. Buy a book (e.g. Petzold) or just do some proper research. Seriously, this API has been around for nearly 30 years now - it's not like it's obscure.

Comment: If this doesn't make sense, then you need a good reference book. Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](http://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) is the Gold Standard in Windows Programming. If you are in a hurry, have a look at [Learn to Program for Windows in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx). Things won't make sense after that, but it's still better than watching YouTube videos (if you are, stop it right there; it's useless, and nothing but a waste of time).

Comment: good to know, I do have a deadline and I usually look for code examples rather than attempting to go through books or documentation because I have found I learn faster that way. I have been looking at youtube vids but you're right, they have not been very useful. I'll have a look through that windows link

Comment: Well, your plan of not laying the base foundations, and trying to write your program without the necessary knowledge isn't panning out very well judging by the code in the question. There are a great many problems with that code. Do yourself a favour and read Petzold's book. It's how the rest of us learnt Win32.

Comment: I understand there are problems, I did mention it was a pseudo-code. Good to know about Petzold's book, I'll look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message loop (GetMessage) won't end until a WM_QUIT message arrives.

You need to implement callback functions for the button click events.

I suggest reading more on button messages here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775941(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The wording of *"callback functions for the mouse click events"* is somewhat misleading. What you really need is a window procedure for the parent window of button controls, which can handle appropriate messages. Those messages are usually **not** the button (or mouse) click events, but rather `WM_COMMAND` messages.